# why is operator-> implemented by operator* in C++ STL library?

Tags: c++, stl

I read `std::deque` source code, I found the following implementations for `_deque_iterator::operator->` and `_deque_iterator::operator*`

```
reference operator* const() { return *cur; }
pointer operator-> const(){ return &(operator*()); }
```

So My question is why not just return `cur` pointer? Like this:

```
pointer operator-> const(){ return cur; }
```

Comment: Which implementation are you looking at? The real STL? gcc's libstdc++? clang's libc++? MSVC? Something else? Which versions?

Comment: Is it important to know where the problem comes from? I think it can be solved without this knowledge :-)

Comment: @Klaus which problem? there is no problem. The question is incomplete without this information.

Comment: This definitely doesn't sound like any modern implementation. The names aren't ugly.

Comment: in dinkumware it'd be `*___cur_`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Actually, more like `*_Mycur`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is more flexible.

If something change, you just have to make a change in one place. If you return `cur` (as you suggested, you have two places you have to change.

Comment: If that's the best argument for it, I'm pretty unimpressed. The STL should be written for performance.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, What makes you think that will be slower? They are both inline, the compiler will generate the same code with both.

Comment: @StilesCrisis it would be inlined, so performance would be expected to be the same. Still, it isn't clear if OP is talking about the STL, or some implementation of the C++ standard library. And if the latter, which one.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Such functions are inlined by compilers anyway, so the performance issues are not coming into play for such them.

Comment: In debug mode, nothing inlines. With a modern compiler in -O3, yes it will inline, but at the cost of a slower compile. I still don't think it's the right tradeoff.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: If that's your argument for making less maintainable code, no matter how slight, I'm not impressed.

Comment: I think it's highly debatable that one is more maintainable than the other. If you're changing the implementation so much that "cur" goes away, you're doing a rewrite.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: For your research, the general principle here is called "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY).

Comment: Somehow I feel like "return x;" is small enough that DRY isn't relevant, right? Come on. That's pedantry at its highest level.

Comment: (also, nothing inlining during debug mode is an issue of the quality of your compiler)

Comment: At any rate, I've seen enough cases where the thing that "will definitely inline" doesn't inline in the real world. Compilers aren't perfect. We can at least not go out of our way to make their jobs harder.

Comment: @Stiles: And I've seen enough cases where methods get out of sync in the real world. People aren't perfect. We can at least not go out of our way to make our jobs harder.

Comment: For the STL, I want the implementation to be lean and efficient. I don't care if the implementors need to work hard to make it that way. For an average person's code, I agree with your priorities, but I value different qualities in a library that's so ubiquitous and widespread. The STL compiling fast matters. The STL not being stupid-inefficient in debug matters. It's okay, I'm willing to agree to disagree on this one. Your points do have merit.

Comment: `return cur` will not cause UB if `cur` is null, but the existing code does. If `operator*` contains an assertion or some other diagnostic tool, that undefined behaviour will be caught there. Together that could be a reason to implement one accessor in terms of the other.

Comment: @Ulrich: Huh. It never crossed my mind that `operator->` can be called outside of the context of member access (which would promptly trigger UB). Technically, I think doing so is undefined behavior anyways, since that's not on the list of expressions guaranteed to be meaningful for any of the iterator concepts.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, @Hurkyl. The accessors are `operator->` and `operator*` for an iterator, because they give you access to the underlying element.

Comment: @Ulrich: I was referring to your first sentence. `InputIterator` requirements are that `i->m` is valid and equivalent to `(*i).m`: nothing about `i.operator->()` being valid (and even that guarantee is only if `i` is dereferenceable). `i->m` will be undefined behavior if `cur` is null; it just happens after the call to `operator->()` rather than during.